# How to use Consolas from fontspec and times simultaneously

Tags: fonts, listings

I want to use `times` in headings but I want to use `Consolas` inside listings, however `times` and `fontspec` overrides one with another. I have tried the following:

```
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{times} % Use the Times font for headings
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%\usepackage{inconsolata}
%\renewcommand*{\ttdefault}{cmtt}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Consolas}
\lstdefinestyle{c++} {%
    language=C++,
    backgroundcolor=\color{format-color!6!white}, % set backgroundcolor
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{keyword},
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily\color{white!10!black},% basic font setting
%... more things down
```

But naturally I doesn't work, my headings are print different with a different font.

I just want the Consolas font in my listings, nothing more. I would really appreciate your help.

Edit: I use my listings next way:

```
% In the class document
\newcommand{\includesilentsnipet}[3]{
    %#1 is the file path
    \lstinputlisting[firstnumber=#2,firstline=#2,lastline=#3]{#1}
}
```

```
% In the document
\includecodeexample{var\_op.cpp}{source/functional/var-op.cpp}
```

Comment: don't use \usepackage{times} with an unicode engine. Set a times font with \setmainfont.

Comment: Please edit your posting to provide an example of how you use `lstlisting` environments.

Comment: @Mico I have edited the post